# How to do a subtraction in a html page on a python variable?

Tags: python, html, django

I have this model:

class Canva(models.Model):

```
name = models.charfield(...

year = models.IntegerField(...
```

In my html page, When I use  {{ canva.year }}, it shows me the year correctly.

how can I see the year before, I tried {{ canva.year-1 }} or {{ canva.year }}-1 and it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simply do

```
{{canva.year|add:"-1" }}
```

or you can create your custom_tempalte tag to subtract values